# Can I stop the REPL locking up when using Emacs and Python?

Tags: python, emacs

If I'm using a python interpreter under EMACS, then I've got various ways of evaluating code, for instance just typing it in at the REPL (*Inferior Python*) If that code produces too much output, then EMACS freezes solid and has to be killed.

This will do it, for instance.

```
[[[False] * 200 for i in range(3)] for j in range(200)]
```

There's no problem at all if python's running in a terminal. It just prints out False 120000 times and gives me the prompt back.

Is there any way to either limit the amount of output the inferior python process produces, or to get EMACS not to explode when faced with large outputs?

In clojure, for example, I can use *print-length* and *print-level* to solve this exact same problem.

Comment: It doesn't freeze solid for me, but the CPU hits 100% - making Emacs very slow, but it still responds. I can end send a keyboard interupt with C-c C-c, which at least kills the offending line, and gets you back to the command prompt. This doesn't fix the problem, but it might save you having to kill Emacs outright.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated calculations by comint-mode are considered the cause.

As for python-mode.el checked in a solution WRT
https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1253907
which makes it work from inside a print in source-buffer, not from shell.

It comes with a couple of new commands prefixed "py-fast-".
Alternatively new option `py-fast-process-p` must be `t'.

Maybe give it a try:

https://launchpad.net/python-mode

However, with python-mode.el and <kbd>M-x IPython RET</kbd>, it doesn't occur, runs nearly as fast as in console.

BTW ipython.el should not be needed.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. There's a python mode in emacs (24.3.1) to start with, and the emacs package manager has a python-mode version 6.0.10 which I tried, but neither of them understand M-x IPython RET (say "no match"). Are you suggesting that I hand install yet another thing called python mode? I'm a little reluctant!

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden v6.0.10 is quite outdated, while M-x ipython RET might work already - the alias M-x IP... RET was introduced later. If you want to use a package-manager, maybe try el-get. If you have bazaar, the trunk might be best: bzr branch lp:python-mode